# Print the indices of a given element in an array using recursion?

Tags: python, arrays, list, recursion, indices

I am trying to write code for returning an array of all indices of a given element in an array

```
arr = [15,11,40,4,4,9]
x = 4
# fsf means count of element 'found so far'
def all_index(arr, i , x, fsf):
    if i == len(arr):
        result = [0] * fsf 
    
    elif arr[i] == x:
        indices = all_index(arr, i + 1, x, fsf + 1)
        indices[fsf] = i
        return indices
        
    else:
        indices = all_index(arr, i + 1, x, fsf)
        return indices
        
        
print(all_index(arr, 0, x, 0))
```

This question already has answers here:
Recursive function returning none in Python [duplicate] (2 answers)

Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.

Closed 3 hours ago.

(Private feedback for you)
Edit question

I am trying to write code for returning an array of all indices of a given element in an array.  fsf means count of element 'found so far'

```
arr = [15,11,40,4,4,9]
x = 4

def all_index(arr, i , x, fsf):
    if i == len(arr):
        result = [0] * fsf 
    
    elif arr[i] == x:
        indices = all_index(arr, i + 1, x, fsf + 1)
        indices[fsf] = i
        return indices
        
    else:
        indices = all_index(arr, i + 1, x, fsf)
        return indices
        
        
print(all_index(arr, 0, x, 0))
```

Expected output: `[3,4]`

To my understanding, the indices array is [0,0] but later it must change to [3,4]

While the code is easy using iteration, I am trying to learn recursion.

Comment: simple answer would be you over complicate stuff and you are not looping over the array in your method

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `append` the index into an array at each recursion where value matches current element of array:

```
ans = []
def all_index(arr, i, x):
    if i is len(arr): return;
    if x is arr[i]:
        ans.append(i)
    all_index(arr, i+1, x)


all_index(arr, 0, x)
print(ans)
```

Comment: This is the right answer since arrays in Python do not have a fixed length. If it was in Java for example, this method would only work with lists and not with arrays.

Comment: Yes, this would work with lists. What if, I create ans as list of size equal to length of the given array with None as elements i.e. ans = [None] * len(arr). Then, is there any way I can change elements in ans with the indices, i.e. [3, 4, None, None, ....] Then, all I have to do is print the elements which are not None.

Comment: Why bother about storing None at all

Comment: To give an impression that the code works with arrays as well in other languages.